# Extracting consecutive array elements except the first in PHP without receiving weird error

Tags: php, arrays

Until recently, I have unused variables as a result of using `list()` to extract only certain elements from an array. I'm trying to do a quick function that retrieves the elements.

Let's say for example, I have a function I call with parameters and it always returns the following in an array

```
Index 0: John Doe
Index 1: 123 Jane Street
Index 2: 902-555-5555
Index 3: Canada
```

If I wanted all the elements, I can easily do something like:

```
list($name,$address,$phone,$country)=functiontogetinfo();
```

And then I can run it through an unused variable tester like PHPMD and it will be happy. However, if I decide to use only the last three values (address, phone, country), then PHPMD will complain about `$name` being an unused variable. This bugs me because I begin to think unused allocated variables waste memory.

I then tried some ways to make things easier both on PHPMD and the computer memory. I tried this on a command line:

```
php -r "list(NULL,$a)=x();echo $a;exit();function x(){return array(1,2);};"
```

I was hoping a "2" would be shown as a result, but instead I get a strange error of:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in Command line code on line 1

If I changed NULL to any variable, the code would compile fine but then PHPMD would complain about an unused variable.

Is it possible for me to get all the elements of an array except for the first one without having to try to go through each index manually and without receiving that weird error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind. I found out online that I simply remove the variable and use nothing in its place. for example:

```
list(,$var2)
```

instead of

```
list(NULL,$var2)
```

Comment: If you were able to answer a question yourself, you should still accept your answer, so the Q gets marked as resolved!